# How to resolve wrong syntax near HAVING COUNT DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct, having

This it the code I am trying to execute:

```
SELECT ID_K
FROM koncert,
     programi 
WHERE koncert.ID_K = programi.ID_K
GROUP BY koncert.ID_K
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT programi.Salla) = 2
```

It returns this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
near 'DISTINCT programi.Salla)=2 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4.
```

Tried to change different things but it still won't work .

Comment: try removing the spurious space between `COUNT` and the opening paren ...  `COUNT(DISTINCT ...`

Comment: The syntax is perfectly fine ANSI SQL. Are you sure you haven't simplified your question?

Comment: @jarlh: MySQL (and MariaDB) don't accept white space between COUNT and the opening paren unless `sql_mode` includes `IGNORE_SPACE`. (Yes, the ANSI standard allows for whitespace, but the MySQL implementation doesn't.)

Comment: @spencer7593, hilarious!!!

Comment: Fixed the white space problem but now  it says ID_K column is ambigous

Comment: @Ravi already answered your question about the (inevitable) "ambiguous column" error.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the count(DISTINCT programi.Salla
) and not count (..) ..remove space between COUNT and (...

```
SELECT koncert.ID_K
FROM koncert
INNER JOIN    programi  on koncert.ID_K = programi.ID_K
GROUP BY koncert.ID_K
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT programi.Salla) = 2
```

but you need also tablename for avoid ambiguity and use explicit join sintax too

Comment: This answer should be upvoted/accepted.. `COUNT (` problem is fixed, same select column names is fixed and this answer is using the better JOIN syntax the old comma JOIN synax is over 25 years old and the old syntax is harder to read..

Comment: @RaymondNijland   . many thanks  for your comment  much appreciated.. .. is strange that a correct  answer   (and with esplicit reccomanation for a newbie)    is downvoted .. ..

Answer (score 0):

First you should use qualified name for your column, when column name is same in both table

```
SELECT ID_K FROM
```

should be

```
SELECT programi.ID_K FROM
```

else, you will get ambiguous column error. Otherwise, your query looks fine except removing extra space when calling `COUNT` (@spencer already mentioned in comment)

Also, it is good practice to join your table using `JOIN` (or `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` etc) keyword, which makes your query more clear and readable.

Comment: In addition to qualifying all column references, i'd also ditch the old school comma operator for the join operation and replace it with the `JOIN` keyword, and move the join predicate from the `WHERE` clause into an `ON` clause ...